# Can I calculate the $x$-coordinate center of mass under the surface $z=xy$ and above three vertices in this way?

Tags: calculus

Can I calculate the $x$-coordinate center of mass under the surface $z=xy$ and above three vertices $(0,1,0)$, $(1,1,0)$, and $(0,2,0)$ in this way?

$$m=\int_0^1 \int_1^{-x+2}\int_0^{xy}1 \cdot dz \, dy \, dx = \frac 5{24}$$

$$x_\text{center}=\frac{M_{yz}}{m}=\frac{24}{5}\int_0^1 \int_1^{-x+2} \int_0^{xy} x \, dz \, dy \, dx = \frac{12}{25}$$